# "Sticky button" configuration under X11/Ubuntu?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xorg

Is there a configuration or app that will enable Sticky-keys like functionality for a pointer button under X11? (On Ubuntu 9.10, FWIW.)  To be clear, I'd like a single tap (down/up events) to be treated as a down event, and a following tap to be treated as an up event.

Context: I have a trackball with a fourth button that I've mapped to act as horizontal/vertical scroll.  This works great.  It'd be even better if I didn't have to hold the button down when scrolling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it turns out, there's currently no way to implement this functionality due to limitations in the evdev input driver as included in Ubuntu 10.04 (Lucid).

In principle, the idea would be to set the "EmulateWheelButton" option and related wheel emulation options, as well as the "DragLockButtons" option to make the wheel emulation button have drag-lock behavior.  Digging into the evdev source reveals that the wheel emulation code and the drag-lock code are currently mutually exclusive -- either the event is handled and dispatched by wheel emulation, or it's handled by the drag-lock code, but not both.

The relevant xorg.conf.d snippet for the configuration *without* drag-lock for a Logitech TrackMan FX is:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "Logitech TrackMan scroll button support"
        MatchIsPointer "on"
        MatchProduct "PS2++ Logitech TrackMan"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "evdev"
        Option "EmulateWheel" "1"
        Option "EmulateWheelButton" "8"
        Option "XAxisMapping" "6 7"
        Option "YAxisMapping" "4 5"
        Option "EmulateWheelTimeout" "0"
        Option "Emulate3Buttons" "0"
EndSection
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `imwheel`.

See also the [Many Buttons Mouse Howto](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ManyButtonsMouseHowto) in Ubuntu Community Documentation.